# Sometimes cannot get current location after turning GPS off and on

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gps, android-gps

I have a React-Native application that needs to use GPS location. Below there is a `LocationFetcher` class that is responsivle for getting current location euther by forcing new location or getting the last one.

Let's say `getLocation()` method is being invoked at the fixed interval. When I turn off the GPS I would get the messages `No location provider found.`, which is fine. But when I **turn** the GPS **on** I would get **no messages** at all. What is more the promise is neither resolved nor rejected. I could toggle GPS many times and let's say on about 5th time all the promises would be resolved with a current location, then I repeat the process and again and have no location at all.

Sometimes launching another app that uses GPS, for example `GPS Viewer` would instantly resolve all the promises and sometimes it doesn't. Often toggling GPS on and off would cause no issues and sometimes it would many. Sometimes turning off the Network would have been causing this problem for like 15 minutes and later on it would have no affect.

Did anyone have such problems with GPS?

```
class LocationFetcher(
  val context: Context
) {

  companion object {
    val LOG_TAG = "LOC_FETCHER"
  }

  /**
   * Gets a location "synchronously" as a Promise
   */
  fun getLocation(forceNewLocation: Boolean, promise: Promise) {
    try {
      if (!areProvidersAvailable()) {
        promise.reject(NATIVE_ERROR, "No location provider found.")
        return
      }
      if (!checkForPlayServices()) {
        promise.reject(NATIVE_ERROR, "Install Google Play Services First and Try Again.")
        return
      }
      if (!hasPermissions()) {
        promise.reject(NATIVE_ERROR, "Appropriate permissions not given.")
        return
      }
      /* --------- */
      if (forceNewLocation) {
        forceSingleGPSLocationUpdate(promise)
        return
      }

      getLastGPSLocation(promise)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Native Location Module ERR - " + ex.toString())
      promise.reject(NATIVE_ERROR, ex.toString())
    }
  }

  @RequiresPermission(
    anyOf = [
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ]
  )
  fun getLastGPSLocation(
    promise: Promise
  ) {
    val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?
    if (locationManager === null) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Location Manager is null")
      promise.reject(LOG_TAG, Exception("Location Manager is null"))
      return
    }

    try {
      val lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
      if (lastKnownLocation === null) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Last known location is null")
        promise.reject(LOG_TAG, "Last known location is null");
        return
      }

      Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Resolving promise with location")
      promise.resolve(convertLocationToJSON(lastKnownLocation))
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.message, e)
      promise.reject(LOG_TAG, e)
      return
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.message, e)
      promise.reject(LOG_TAG, e)
      return
    }
  }

  @RequiresPermission(
    anyOf = [
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ]
  )
  fun forceSingleGPSLocationUpdate(
    promise: Promise
  ) {
    val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?
    if (locationManager === null) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Location Manager is null")
      promise.reject(LOG_TAG, Exception("Location Manager is null"))
      return
    }

    try {
      val locationListener = object : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
          if (location === null) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Location changed is null")
            promise.reject(LOG_TAG, Exception("Location changed is null"))
            return
          }

          Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Resolving promise with location")
          promise.resolve(convertLocationToJSON(location))
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}

        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
      }

      locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, locationListener, null)
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.message, e)
      promise.reject(LOG_TAG, e)
      return
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.message, e)
      promise.reject(LOG_TAG, e)
      return
    }
  }

  fun areProvidersAvailable(): Boolean {
    val lm = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    return try {
      lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
        lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString())
      false
    }
  }

  fun hasPermissions(): Boolean {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
      context,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
      || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
      context,
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
  }

  // ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
  // 22493465/check-if-correct-google-play-service-available-unfortunately-application-has-s
  internal fun checkForPlayServices(): Boolean {
    val googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
      if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
        val map = WritableNativeMap().also {
          it.putInt("resultCode", resultCode)
          it.putInt("resolutionRequest", PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
        }
        sendLocalEventToModule(LOCAL_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR, map)
      }
      return false
    }
    return true
  }

  internal fun convertLocationToJSON(l: Location?): WritableMap {
    if (l === null) {
      return WritableNativeMap().also {
        it.putString("error", "Received location was null")
      }
    }
    return WritableNativeMap().also {
      it.putDouble("latitude", l.latitude)
      it.putDouble("longitude", l.longitude)
      it.putDouble("accuracy", l.accuracy.toDouble())
      it.putDouble("altitude", l.altitude)
      it.putDouble("bearing", l.bearing.toDouble())
      it.putString("provider", l.provider)
      it.putDouble("speed", l.speed.toDouble())
      it.putString("timestamp", l.time.toString())
    }
  }

  internal fun sendLocalEventToModule(eventName: String, data: WritableMap) {
    val intent = Intent(eventName).also {
      it.putExtra("data", WritableMapWrapper(data))
    }

    Log.v(TAG, "Sending local event ${eventName}")
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)
  }
}
```

I don't know if this is important, but we are getting location via Foreground Service, which is presented below.

```
class ForegroundLocationService : Service() {
  lateinit var locationFetcher : LocationFetcher

  override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
  }

  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    return START_NOT_STICKY
  }

  override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    stopSelf()
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    locationFetcher = LocationFetcher(applicationContext)

    /**
     * Saving this [ForegroundLocationService] reference to the static variable,
     * because when binding a Service using [bindService] it would not stop the
     * this service, even though the app would close
     */
    LocationModule.foregroundLocationService = this
    showNotification()
    Log.v(TAG, "Creating Foreground Location Service")
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    LocationModule.foregroundLocationService = null
    locationFetcher.stopLocationUpdates()
    Log.v(TAG, "Destroying Foreground Location Service")
  }

  fun showNotification() {
    val channelId =
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createNotificationChannel()
      } else {
        // In Android versions before Oreo channel ID is not used
        // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#NotificationCompat.Builder(android.content.Context)
        ""
      }

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
      .setOngoing(true)
      .setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
      .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
      .setTicker(NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
      .build()

    Log.v(TAG, "Showing a notification")

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
  }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
  private fun createNotificationChannel(): String {
    val channelId = "app_gps_service"
    val channelName = NOTIFICATION_TITLE
    val chan = NotificationChannel(
      channelId,
      channelName,
      NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
    )
    chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
    chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
    val service = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    service.createNotificationChannel(chan)

    Log.v(TAG, "Created notification channel, because SDK version is ${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}")
    return channelId
  }

  companion object {
    val TAG = "ForegroundLocationSvc"
    val NOTIFICATION_ID = 101
    val NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "GPS Service"

    @JvmStatic
    fun start(context: Context) {
      Log.v(TAG, "Starting Foreground Location Service")

      val intent = Intent(context, ForegroundLocationService::class.java)
      context.startService(intent)
    }
  }
}
```

Below There is our manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.myapp">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
  <!-- push notifications permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

  <permission
    android:name="com.ticketing.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="com.ticketing.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

  <permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>

    <!-- GPS Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".gps.GpsLocationReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
      android:name=".location.ForegroundLocationService"
      android:description="@string/foreground_location_service_desc"
      android:exported="false"
      android:stopWithTask="false">
    </service>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The "last location" isn't always available. This is normal. It will become available (after a while) when any application requests location updates. You are seeing normal and intended Android behaviour. Since you already have the mechanism to force a location update in your code, just set `forceNewLocation` to `true`.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen but even when i set forceNewLocation it is still hanging. `onLocationChanged` is not being invoked in that case